# Passing custom variable properties into foreach statement

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass multiple variables into one foreach statement using custom properties but the custom property is not being passed inside the foreach statement

```
$input = "one two three"

$tests = "true false true"

Add-Member -InputObject $tests -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $input



foreach ($test in $tests) {

    Write-Host $test.Name
    Write-Host $test

}
```

expected output:

```
one
true
two
false
three
true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what is the real output that you currently get?

Comment: `$input` is forbidden name for a variable https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html
`$tests` `$input` are strings not arrays change both to an array `$tests = "one","two","three"` so that foreach loop will work for each word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are lot of things to address. First of all the `foreach` loop works on array. 
So your variable declaration is wrong. It has to be comma separated or it has to be in an array format.

like this

```
$input = "one", "two", "three"

$tests = "true", "false", "true"
```

OR

```
$input = @("one", "two", "three")

$tests = @("true", "false", "true")
```

`Foreach` loop cannot operation on multiple arrays at a while ; in your case you should be using `For` loop like

```
$input = "one", "two", "three"

$tests = "true", "false", "true"


foreach ($test in $tests) ## For looping through single array
{
    Write-Host $test
}

If($input.Length -match $tests.Length)  ## Forlooping through multiple arrays
{
    For($i=0;$i -lt $input.Length; $i++) 
    {
        "$($input[$i]) :: $($tests[$i])"
    }
}
```

and for **your Expected Format**, it should be:

```
$input = "one", "two", "three"

$tests = @("true", "false", "true")

If($input.Length -match $tests.Length) 
{
    For($i=0;$i -lt $input.Length; $i++) 
    {
        "$($input[$i])"
        "$($tests[$i])"
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
one 
true 
two 
false 
three 
true
```

PS: Now you can easily incorporate the `Add-Member -InputObject $tests -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $input` based on this logic.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Randips's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473430/passing-custom-variable-properties-into-foreach-statement/56473681#56473681), you have some issues with the setup/use of your 'array', which he addresses.

In terms of adding custom properties, I think you are running into the [immutability of strings in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93091/why-cant-strings-be-mutable-in-java-and-net).  Once created they can't be changed, so you aren't able to add new members.  Other types work fine.  For example, you can do this with a process object:

```
$propValue= "one two three"

$proc= (Get-Process)[33]

Add-Member -InputObject $proc -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "MyProperty" -Value $propValue

Write-Host $proc.MyProperty
Write-Host $proc
```

Which gives output like this:

```
one two three
System.Diagnostics.Process (devenv)
```